# Selecting a single output from functions that return multiple values (python)

Tags: python, function, loops

So I have a function which returns 3 variables, and I want to use a for loop to get an array of each of these variables if that makes any sense. This is what I have so far and I get the error:

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

```
Import numpy as np
def position(min, max):
    x=np.random.uniform(min,max)
    y=np.random.uniform(min,max)
    z=np.random.uniform(min,max)
return x,y,z

x,y,z=[position(0,100) for _ in range(1000)]
```

Note that I can't move the loop within the function itself because I need to be able to call the function to generate single values as well. Is there a function I can use to achieve what I want (3 arrays with of dimension 1000)?

Comment: not an answer to your question, but your code has some issues `import` instead of `Import`, your indentation for your `return` is incorrect, and you are shadowing the built-in `min` and `max` functions with your argument names.

Comment: ^^ yeh sorry hadn't copied my code onto this website before so was having some difficulties copying it across

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want here is to `zip` the resulting array:

```
x, y, z = zip(*[position(0,100) for _ in range(1000)])
```

But this will give you 3 tuples. If you want numpy arrays, you must explicitely convert them:

```
x, y, z = (np.array(i) for i in zip(*[position(0,100) for _ in range(1000)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change like this:

```
arr = [position(0,100) for _ in range(1000)]
```

You will get `arr` with tuples:

```
print(arr[:2])
```

Output:

```
[(94.38888058610041, 82.97455003388289, 56.356363837769564),
 (28.925535522819914, 62.10586090326522, 3.7630479522948956)]
```